# Could anyone explain ge_frombytes_vartime for me?

Tags: monerod, cryptography

Recently I am working on monero source code, and I wonder how monero verify ed25519 public key is invalid. Is this function converting the public key into Y coordinates, then calculating the X coordinates, and verifying whether the coordinate points are on the elliptic curve? I was confused about the converting process.
And also, does any Y coordinates have a corresponding X coordinates? Why this verify process will be failed if public key is invalid?
Thanks so much!
[ge_frombytes_vartime is here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c#L1333).

Answer (score 0):

Monero's `crypto_verify_ed25519` checks validity through deriving and comparing public keys with messages and signatures without requiring x-y coordinates.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is not clear. What I want to know is how monero checks whether a ed25519 public key is valid, not a signature. And I found the function `ge_frombytes_vartime` during the check process. It seems to check whether the (x,y) is on the ed25519 curve or not. But I'm not sure.

Comment: And I can't find `crypto_verify_ed25519` you mentioned. Is it a function name or file name?